# Dialog passing a value to another dialog on button click

Tags: reporting, x++, axapta

I am wondering if this is possible, and believe it is with the dialog.

I have a menu item button on a form which runs a report, and when this is clicked the user is shown a dialog form which copies the unique ID of the selected values from the form.

At the bottom there is a button which runs another report, this is only run from time to time and must run off that button, this part works fine.

What I need to happen is that, when the button to run the second report is clicked, the current selected values are passed to that report. Now this cannot be done in the normal way as values have already been passed to the first report, so I would assume the values must be copied from the first dialog to the second?

If so can someone please assist with how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the report is a MorphX report (not SSRS) and the dialog is in a class extending `RunBaseReport`.

Make a parm method for each dialog field in the first and second report.

Then in the main report of the second report feed the values of the first report like this:

```
static void main(Args args)
{
    SecondReport report = new SecondReport();
    report.getLast(); // to fetch saved values
    // args.caller() must be set in FirstReport
    report.parmItemId(args.caller().parmItemId()); // ItemId to be passed around
    if (report.prompt())
        report.run();
}
```

Comment: Jan, I have the Parm part working, however I can't seem to get the first line of the main code working?
I cannot seem to declare the report either in classDeclaration or in the Main method?

Comment: You will need a `RunBaseReport` class with a public `new` method to declare it. A report by itself cannot be be used as a type.

Comment: Hi Jan, again thanks for all your help with this. I now have a class running the first report, this works off the form, and a second class running the second report off the form, this works fine. The first class when run shows the dialog, and on that dialog I have a button to run the second report, but when this is run the second dialog has no values. However, I can get the second report to run with the values if I just click "OK" on the first dialog, which is really strange. This does the job however I would really like it running off a menuitembutton on a the first dialog?

Comment: Your runbase variables in the first class have not been set yet. You should call `getFromDialog` from the `clicked` method of the button before calling `super()`.